# Sql Server: include column that is not part of an aggregate function or Group by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by

I have a StudentGrades table that has these columns:

```
 StudentID | CourseID | Grade
```

I need to find the top student for each course(along with the course id and the grade thye got for the course. For example if there are a total of three courses taught at the school the query should return:

```
1111  3  93
2334  4  90
4343  6  100
```

Here's what I have so far.  The following query

```
select CourseID, MAX(Grade) Grade 
from StudentGrades group by CourseID;
```

Produces:

```
3   83
4   90
6   100
```

What is the best way to include the studentID column?  I know that I can hold the above result in a temp table and join with the the original StudentGrades table where the CourseID and Score match the get the correct columns.  Is there another way or better way to include StudentID?

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SQL Server` has a functionality for windowing functions.

```
WITH gradeList
AS
(
    SELECT  StudentID,
            CourseID, 
            Grade,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CourseID
                                ORDER BY Grade DESC) RN
    FROM    tableName
)
SELECT  StudentID,
        CourseID, 
        Grade
FROM    gradeList
WHERE   rn = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9ff93/1)
- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d59d1/1)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*with duplicate student having the same score with the highest grade*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d869/1)

Comment: Is Windowing a newly added feature to sql Server?