# HOWTO: Include column that is not part of an aggregate function or Group by clause in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by, sql-server-2008-r2, with-statement

I have below recursive CTE:

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    PARENT_TEST_ID int,
    TEST_ID  int,
    VALIDATED int,
    ERR int
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(NULL, 1, 0, 0),
(NULL, 2, 0, 0),
(1,3,0, 0),
(1,4,0, 0),
(2,5,0, 0),
(2,6,0, 0),
(2,7,0, 0),
(7,8,0, 1)

;with C as
(
  select TEST_ID, PARENT_TEST_ID, (CASE WHEN ERR=1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS VALIDATED, ERR
  from @T
  where TEST_ID not in (select PARENT_TEST_ID 
                   from @T 
                   where PARENT_TEST_ID is not null) AND PARENT_TEST_ID IS NOT NULL
  union all
  select 
  T.TEST_ID, 
  T.PARENT_TEST_ID, 
  (case when t.TEST_ID=c.PARENT_TEST_ID and c.VALIDATED=1 AND T.ERR=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as VALIDATED,
  T.ERR
  from @T as T
    inner join C
      on T.TEST_ID = C.PARENT_TEST_ID 
)
SELECT DISTINCT PARENT_TEST_ID, TEST_ID, MIN(VALIDATED) FROM C
GROUP BY TEST_ID
```

But I cannot include PARENT_TEST_ID column in the result SELECT as it is not part of the group by clause, so I have found this link:

[Including column that is not part of the group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15060604/sql-server-include-column-that-is-not-part-of-an-aggregate-function-or-group-by)

So now I am trying to do the same in my case, I am trying to apply John Woo solution but I do not know how. Any help? Or any other best solution?

Comment: I have given you an answer to the question you have asked, but from your test data I do not think that it is actually what you are looking to do.  Can you please include your desired output if my answer below is not what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Just change your last line to `GROUP BY PARENT_TEST_ID, TEST_ID`

The error you are getting is telling you that you can't add columns to the output if you don't either aggregate on it or group your other aggregates by it.  By adding the column to the `group by`, you are telling SQL Server that you want to do your `min` by both the parent and the test ID values.

rextester: http://rextester.com/JRF55398

Answer (score 0):

iamdave is right, but if you want to implement John Woo's solution from that linked answer, it would look like this:

rextester: http://rextester.com/QQQGM79701

```
;with C as (
  select 
     test_id
   , parent_test_id
   , validated=(case when err = 1 then 0 else 1 end) 
   , err
  from @T as t
  where t.test_id not in (
    select i.parent_test_id
    from @T as i
    where i.parent_test_id is not null
    )
   and t.parent_test_id is not null
  union all
  select 
     t.test_id
   , t.parent_test_id
   , validated = case 
      when t.test_id = c.parent_test_id
        and c.validated = 1
        and t.err = 0 
      then 1 
      else 0 
      end
    , t.err
  from @T as T
    inner join c on t.test_id = c.parent_test_id
)
, r as (
  select 
     parent_test_id
   , test_id
   , Validated
   , rn = row_number() over (
        partition by test_id 
        order by Validated
    )
  from C
)
select 
     parent_test_id
   , test_id
   , Validated
  from r 
  where rn=1
```